# Memory leak due to continuous opening and closing of XML File

Tags: c, xml, multithreading, xml-parsing, libxml2

I am calling this code snippet inside a thread. But I'm getting memory leak.Is it due to continuous opening and closing of the File?If so, how can i solve this issue?

```c
if(g_readFromDataFile == TRUE)
{   
    xmlDocPtr file = NULL;
    xmlInitParser();
    file = xmlReadFile("DataFile.xml",NULL,XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS);
    xmlFreeDoc(file);
    xmlCleanupParser();                 
}
```

I tried calling this code inside a `while(1)` loop outside this thread but didn't come across any memory leak.
Adding more details...
The thread is being created inside a function and is running continuously without a close.Inside this thread if the global variable is set 1 i should Read values from the file also i need to use another function to update parameters into the file.But since i got memory leak i cut down the entire code to find the source and found that leak happens even if the code is only to open and close.Is this an issue with the thread?

Comment: Functions like `xmlInitParser()` and `xmlCleanupParser()` which don't take any arguments and don't return anything most probably deal with global variables of some kind. Thus they are quite likely not thread save.

Comment: What led you to think there's a memory leak?

Comment: And why do you keep rereading the same file?

Comment: Continuously reading the file to update values from the file to UI.

Comment: I can see the memory being used up so much in the task manager.Also I'm getting stackoverflow.

Comment: Why are you opening a closing the file?  If you are using the XML as a log file than just append the data to the end of the xml like most people.  The xml will not be well formed but that is what everybody else does with an xml log file.

Comment: Never call `xmlCleanupParser` unless it's the very last thing your program does before exiting. Calling it from randomly from threads is unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading the same file every time then just open it once at the beginning and close it when you are finally done (may be just before exiting the program). You will need to pass the file descriptor to functions which read the file. There is no need to keep opening and closing the file every time a file read is needed. May be you will need to change your code for this.

Comment: File reading is happening inside the thread only if the global variable is set true.This thread runs continuous to send packets from server to client.I need to read the file and update the pointer which contains data to be sent.

Comment: How are you finding the memory leak? What is the method that you are using to find the memory leak? As you have said that running in a while(1) loop doesn't cause any memory leak, then this means that memory leak is in some other code. Can you please post the complete code of the function that is run in the thread and also the complete code of the function which starts the thread?

You have also mentioned that you are getting stack overflow - this means that probably there is an infinite recursion somewhere in your code.

Comment: Memory corresponding to console is increasing in the task manager.

Comment: void XMLFileTest()
{
    while (1) 
 {
        xmlDocPtr dataFile = NULL;
  xmlInitParser();
  dataFile =  xmlReadFile("DataFile.xml", NULL, 256);
        if (dataFile != NULL) 
  {
            
            xmlFreeDoc(dataFile);
   xmlCleanupMemory();
        }
  Sleep(300);
        
        
    }
}  This is the thread being run.

Comment: If dataFile is NULL then you are not calling xmlCleanupParser()/xmlCleanupMemory(). This may be the reason of memory leak. Can you check this?

Comment: checked still issue persists

Comment: You have also mentioned that you are getting stack overflow - this means that probably there is an infinite recursion somewhere in your code or you are doing the same thing many many times. Please check this. Please post as much code as you can otherwise it will be difficult to find the problem.